# Why is the Eclipse IDE giving me "editor does not contain a main type" even though I have a main?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java and in an attempt to make library installation easier, I've decided to use Eclipse IDE. However, my code is not compiling because it says "launch error: Editor does not contain a main type"

[Here you can see what the layout of my project folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trmov.png)

It's a beginner's project, so there is a folder called src and inside there is another called ww. Inside this one, there are two files, `connectToData.java` and `Main.java`. The connect file contains a structure like this:

```
package ww;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class connectToData {
    public connectToData() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    public static JSONObject getData(String query) {
        String u = "https://sky.esa.int/esasky-tap/tap/sync?request=doQuery&lang=ADQL&format=json&query=";
        query = "SELECT+TOP+10+,*+FROM+observations.mv_v_v_hst_mmi_observation_optical_fdw_fdw";
        URL url;
```

And my `Main.java` has a structure like this:

```
package ww;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, please fix the problems with this code");
```

They both don't have any other classes or functions inside. Why am I not able to run my code, even though I clearly have a `public static void main`?

Comment: Thank you kindly @user16320675, what is the appropriate structure in this case?

Answer (score 0):

That outlined 'J' means:

**This is a java file, but, is not part of any source folder.**

Which means you can't run these.

Projects are complex beasts. You don't *just* have source files - you have a so-called 'source folder'. For example, you could have an application that has test code, a separate installer project, and a plugin for photoshop, in addition to a main app. Obviously, you would want to separate these things out, so that the build tools can for example *not* include the test code in the plugin, that'd be weird.

As a consequence, projects have so-called 'source folders'. You need at least one, and you can have more than one if you want. In fact, the 'standard model' of what maven projects look like specifically *requires* that your main app is in `src/main/java`, for example.

Given that you must have source folders, that also means you can put java files outside of a source folder. And when you do that, you get that J-outline icon as your screenshot shows. As far as eclipse is concerned, these files aren't runnable at all. Perhaps they exist as a template for something (no different from an icon file), or as part of documentation.

The solution is to put these files inside a source folder. The information you provided doesn't let me give you a specific series of steps, but, generally, rightclick on your 'ww' project, find the build settings, add a source folder. Then drag the files you have into the source folder.